# How do we know/why do we assume the mishkan's components were rectangular?

Tags: architecture-design, mishkan-tabernacle, ark-aron-kodesh

The sizes of the objects in the *mishkan* are mostly described in terms of 3 lengths.

E.g. [שמות כה:י](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.25.10?lang=he&aliyot=0):

> וְעָשׂ֥וּ אֲר֖וֹן עֲצֵ֣י שִׁטִּ֑ים אַמָּתַ֨יִם וָחֵ֜צִי אָרְכּ֗וֹ וְאַמָּ֤ה וָחֵ֙צִי֙ רָחְבּ֔וֹ וְאַמָּ֥ה וָחֵ֖צִי קֹמָתֽוֹ

and [שמות כה:כג](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.25.23?lang=he&aliyot=0):

> וְעָשִׂ֥יתָ שֻׁלְחָ֖ן עֲצֵ֣י שִׁטִּ֑ים אַמָּתַ֤יִם אָרְכּוֹ֙ וְאַמָּ֣ה רָחְבּ֔וֹ וְאַמָּ֥ה וָחֵ֖צִי קֹמָתֽוֹ

and [שמות כז:א](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.27.1?lang=he&aliyot=0):

> וְעָשִׂ֥יתָ אֶת־הַמִּזְבֵּ֖חַ עֲצֵ֣י שִׁטִּ֑ים חָמֵשׁ֩ אַמּ֨וֹת אֹ֜רֶךְ וְחָמֵ֧שׁ אַמּ֣וֹת רֹ֗חַב רָב֤וּעַ יִהְיֶה֙ הַמִּזְבֵּ֔חַ וְשָׁלֹ֥שׁ אַמּ֖וֹת קֹמָתֽוֹ

These tell us the *sizes* in each dimension but don't say anything about the shape. [**How] do we know that they were rectangular in any/all dimensions?** I don't have specific alternative shapes in mind, but could these measurements not be the length of the longest part of each piece with edges of some other shape, or of straight edges which join at some other angles?

- The word *"ravu'a"* in the case of the *mizbe'ach* seems to refer to
  size and not shape - albeit relative size. [Ibn Ezra on the spot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.27.1?lang=he&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=he)
  states it in these terms: "any shape whose length is [equal to] its
  width is called *ravu'a*".
- In the case of the *aron*, the Amora'im
  [discussing](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.14a.9?lang=he) how the tablets fit inside seem to assume things were
  rectangular, I think. Otherwise it would be strange to have a
  discussion with such precision about the interior space.

I don't recall an explicit discussion of the shapes of these vessels - although I know there are such discussions about the *m'nora* and the *kiyor* - and the widespread convention seems to be to depict/reconstruct them as having rectangular surfaces ([e.g.](http://hamikdash.org.il/%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9/%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%98-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9F/)).

Comment: [This guy's](http://project314.org/) theories were all the rage on certain corners of Facebook a couple of years ago.

Comment: You do have a decent argument, here. With the possible exception of the term *ravu'a* which I think means "square". It is related to the word "reva" implying 4, so that seems to imply a cubic / rectangular object. The rest of the objects describe 3 dimensions. Technically, it could be pyramidal.

Comment: Within this discussion, the Aron mentions 2 poles. Practically, I can't see carrying a pyramid on 2 poles and balancing it properly. I don't know. The *shulchan* has a "crown" around it and it mentions a length and width, I believe. Once it mentions a 2-dimensional object to fit something else and surround it, I think that limits it the base object to being rectangular, no? My geometry isn't perfect. The menorah also may require a rectangular base, "practically". It's already not completely rectangular, anyway.

Comment: @DanF Two reasons I don't think _ravu'a_ means _square_ - i.e. equilateral and equiangular: 1. We have no indication from the other measurements that they are specifying straight lines (imagine for argument's sake, giving the dimensions of an ellipse as just a length and width). 2. This is the only horizontal surface whose two dimensions are the same, which could be the meaning of the special designation. Ibn Ezra's comment says this explicitly. Even more explicit is _Hak'sav V'hakabala_ on the spot, who says the _mizbe'ach_ could be any size as long as these two dimensions were the same.

Comment: @DanF Re structures that have matching dimensions but no rectangular surfaces, imagine fitting a "crown" atop a table like [these](http://webx.ubi.pt/~hgil/P.V.2/Ilusoes-Visuais/TABLE_ILLUSION.gif) (in which the angles are not showing depth but are really as they appear in the picture). It should be totally doable.